# Steam is stuck on login, assertion 'regex != NULL' failed

Tags: games, steam

Good day!

I have a problem installing Steam on my machine:

1. The clients successfully downloads and installs itself. After installation it presents me the login window.
2. After I type in my credentials, login window hangs without any reaction to any input.
3. If I kill the steam process and restart it, it opens the window "Connecting Steam account: [my username]", which hangs again.

In the terminal some the last lines which the client prints are:

```
(steam:16767): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 properties support

(steam:16767): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_replace_eval: assertion `regex != NULL' failed

(steam:16767): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_regex_unref: assertion `regex != NULL' failed
```

**I've tried:**

- installing steam from official website and from ubuntu repo, even old 1.0.0.45 version
- deleting `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/Steam` then redownloading the client.

No change.

**My system:** elementary OS 0.4 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.

I suppose steam's bundled glib conflicts with glib installed on my system. But I don't know what to do with this.

I hope someone would help me on this issue. Thanks!